# AutoMapperMapping: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I try for the last 2 days to create simple INNER JOIN using aspnetboilerplate and I`m getting error that I really don`t know how to handle.
My opinion is that somehow I need to add two DTO inside ObjectMapper.Map

My code :

StudentDto

```
[AutoMap(typeof(Student))]
public class Student: EntityDto
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Last_Name{ get; set; }
    public int City_Id { get; set; }
}
}
```

CityDto

```
[AutoMap(typeof(City))]
public class CityDto : EntityDto
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
}
```

StudentAppService.cs

```
 private readonly IRepository<Student> _studentRepository;
   private readonly IRepository<City> _cityRepository;


    public StudentAppService(IRepository<Student> _studentRepository, IRepository<City> _cityRepository)
    {
         _studentRepository = studentRepository ;
       _cityRepository = cityRepository ;
     }

    public List<StudentDto> GetStudentWithCityName()
    {
        var data = (from s in _studentRepository.GetAll() join c in _cityRepository.GetAll() on s.City_Id equals c.Id select new { name = s.Name }).ToList();
        return ObjectMapper.Map<List<StudentDto>>(data);

    }
```

When I build application and try to do GET with SWAGGER I get this error (with the value of data that I want )

[image]

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: You're selecting an anonymous object (`new { ... }`) from the repo, not a `Student`, but configured a mapping between `StudentDto` and `Student`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you do the

> "select new { name = s.Name }"

The object cannot be anonymous, it has to be an object that exists and has the AutoMap attribute, to be able to map it, or you can directly select the StudentDto object.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the dataType of the prop 'Last_Name' be a 'int'? it's not supposed to be a string?